# Delete all products in trash through phpMyAdmin - Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

I know how to delete all products in WooCommerce, but I don't know how to delete all products in trash. Does any of you know how to? I have looked on it, and I think I got an idea, but I don't wan't to ruin anything.

I got this for deletion of all products.

```
DELETE FROM wp__term_relationships WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp__posts WHERE post_type = 'product');

DELETE FROM wp__postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp__posts WHERE post_type = 'product');

DELETE FROM wp__posts WHERE post_type = 'product';

DELETE FROM wp__posts WHERE post_type = 'product_variation';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nvm got it sorted out :)
Forgot that trash products are still defined as products under the 'post_type'

Comment: Write it up as an answer to this question, please! It makes it easier for others with similar problems to find your solution.

Comment: I just deleted all products. Trash was included with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these queries:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID 
                  FROM wp_posts 
                  WHERE post_status = 'trash' AND post_type IN ('product','product_variation'))
```

and

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_status = 'trash' and post_type IN ('product','product_variation')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also pls format the code correctly.